# Decimal Representation vs Decimal Expansion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

What does it mean when they ask you to write the decimal representation of a number.

Looking it up Google for a while,

On some pages, it means to write the value of the number. While on others it means to write it in a form of series.
What does it mean when I say, find the decimal representation of $\dfrac{123456}{100}$
Does it mean $1234.56$ or $1 \cdot 10^3 + 2 \cdot 10^2 + 3 \cdot 10^1 + 4 \cdot 10^0 + 5 \cdot 10^{-1} + 6 \cdot 10^{-2}$?

Also what is the difference between Decimal Expansion and Decimal Representation?

Answer (score 2):

Since $1234.56$ is shorthand for $1 \times 10^3 + 2 \times 10^2 + 3 \times 10^1 + 4 \times 10^0 + 5 \times 10^{-1} + 6 \times 10^{-2}$, there is really no difference between these possibilities. And there is also no difference between decimal expansion and decimal representation.

Comment: But then I can argue that there is really no difference between $\frac{123456}{100}$ and $1234.56$ either. What "difference" are you referring to?

Comment: @William SInce I wrote “there is […] no difference” **twice**, I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: "there's really no difference between these possibilities" ... What "difference" are you talking about?

Comment: I'm just saying that both expressions, although they look different, have the same meaning.

Comment: exactly and along the same lines, $\frac{123456}{100} $ and $1234.56$ look different but have the same meaning. But $\frac{123456}{100}$ is not the decimal representation of itself. Then the "difference" you speak of has no relevance whatsoever with the decimal representation.